# Is it time for a has_many: : through controller? And if so, what does that look like?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm creating an app that lets the user track their board games. There's a master library for adding board games to the user's personal library. Something in my code has made these two libraries more or less synonymous. Every time I drop and remigrate my database, it adds all of the games from the master library to the user library automatically.

But that's not the problem I want to work with, it's just along the same lines. When I hit my axios.delete function for removing a board game from the person library, it triggers deletion of the board game from the master library too. As I have my backend set up currently, my user has_many board_games and board_games has_many users. I think my axios.delete is hitting my destroy function in the general board_game controller rather that user_board_games (even though that's where I'm sending it) and so I think I need to create a controller specific to user_board_games. But my research on has_many through only gives me the most basic set up.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'; 
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button, Card, Container, Dropdown, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class Games extends Component {

  state = { games:[], user_games: [], showGames: false, sort: "A-Z" }
    const userId = this.props.user.id 
    axios.get('/api/board_games')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data)
        this.setState({games: res.data});
      })
    axios.get(`/api/users/${userId}/board_games`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data); 
        this.setState({user_games: res.data});
      } )

  }

  toggleGames = () => {
    this.setState({ showGames: !this.state.showGames })
  }

  removeGame = (id) => {
    const userId = this.props.user.id 
    axios.delete(`/api/users/${userId}/board_games/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  }

  addGame = (id) => {
    const userId = this.props.user.id 
    axios.post(`api/users/${userId}/board_games`, { userId, id })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
  }

  dropDownMenu = () => {
    return  ( <Dropdown text='Sort'>
              <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Dropdown.Item text='A-Z' onClick={() => this.setState({sort: "A-Z"}) }/>
                <Dropdown.Item text='Z-A' onClick={() => this.setState({sort: "Z-A"})} />
                <Dropdown.Item text='Time Needed' onClick={() =>this.setState({sort: "Time Needed"})}  />
              </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
    )
  }

  userLibrary = () => {
    const {user_games, sort} = this.state 
    switch(sort) {
      case 'A-Z':
        user_games.sort(function(game1, game2){
          if(game1.title < game2.title) {return -1; }
          if(game1.title > game2.title) {return 1; }
          return 0; 
        }); 
        break; 
      case 'Z-A':
      user_games.sort(function(game1, game2){
        if(game1.title > game2.title) {return -1; }
        if(game1.title < game2.title) {return 1; }
        return 0; 
      }); 
        break; 
      case 'Time Needed': 
        user_games.sort(function(game1,game2){
          return game1.time_needed-game2.time_needed 
        }) 
        break; 
      default: 
      user_games.sort(function(game1, game2){
        if(game1.title < game2.title) {return -1; }
        if(game1.title > game2.title) {return 1; }
        return 0; 
      }); 
    }
    return user_games.map( game => 
      <Card key={game.id}>
        <Card.Content>
          <Card.Header>{game.title}</Card.Header>
          <Card.Description>Players: {game.min_players} - {game.max_players}</Card.Description>
          <Card.Description>Company: {game.company}</Card.Description>
          <Card.Description>Time Needed: {game.time_needed}</Card.Description>
        </Card.Content>
        <Card.Content extra> 
              <Button basic color='red' onClick={() => this.removeGame(game.id)}>
                Remove from Library
              </Button>
          </Card.Content>
      </Card> 
    )
  }

  gamesList = () => {
//gives each game with a link to more info
    const { games, user_games } = this.state 
    return games.map( game =>
        <Card key={game.id}>
          <Card.Content>
            <Card.Header>{game.title}</Card.Header>
            <Card.Description>Players: {game.min_players} - {game.max_players}</Card.Description>
            <Card.Description>Company: {game.company}</Card.Description>
            <Card.Description>Time Needed: {game.time_needed}</Card.Description>
          </Card.Content>
          { user_games.include ? (
          <Card.Content extra>
              <Button basic color='green' onClick={() => this.addGame(game.id)}>
                Add to Library
              </Button>
          </Card.Content>
          ) 
            : (
          <Card.Content extra> 
              <Button basic color='red' onClick={() => this.removeGame(game.id)}>
                Remove from Library
              </Button>
          </Card.Content>
          )  
          }
        </Card> 
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { showGames } = this.state 
    return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Games</h1>
        <Grid>
          <Grid.Column floated="left" width={2}>
            <h3>Your Games</h3>
          </Grid.Column> 
          <Grid.Column floated="right" width={2}>
            {this.dropDownMenu()}
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>
        <Card.Group itemsPerRow={4}>{this.userLibrary()}</Card.Group>
        { showGames ? (
            <div>
              <Button basic onClick={this.toggleGames}>Done Adding</Button>
              <Card.Group itemsPerRow={4}>{this.gamesList()}</Card.Group> 
            </div>
        )
          : (
          <Button basic onClick={this.toggleGames}>Add a Game</Button>
        ) 
        }
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { user: state.user };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Games);
```

Here is the board game controller:

```
class Api::BoardGamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_board_game, except: [:index]


  def index
    render json: BoardGame.all
  end

  def show
    render json: @board_game
  end

  def create
    board_game = BoardGame.new(board_game_params)
    if board_game.save
      render json: board_game 
    else
      render json: board_game.errors
    end 
  end

  def update
    if @board_game.update(board_game_params)
      render json: @board_game 
    else 
      render_error(@board_game)
    end 
  end

  def destroy 
    binding.pry 
    @board_game.destroy 
  end 

  private 

  def set_board_game 
    @board_game = BoardGame.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def board_game_params
    params.require(:board_game).permit(
    :title,
    :min_players,
    :max_players,
    :base_game,
    :time_needed,
    :company 
    )
  end 

end
```

the board game model:

```
class BoardGame < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :game_sessions, through: :game_session_games 
  has_many :users, through: :user_board_games
  has_many :rounds 
end
```

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :board_games, through: :user_board_games
  has_many :game_sessions 
  # User.joins(:board_games).where("board_games.id == 'user.id'")
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

userBoardGame model:

```
class UserBoardGame < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user 
belongs_to :board_game   
end
```

So what goes here in the user_board_games_controller.rb?

```
class Api::UserBoardGamesController < ApplicationController
  def destroy 
    @user.board_game.destroy 
  end 

end
```

Comment: You probably don't need to show that much code. also `@user.board_game` doesn't make sense when a user has many board games

Answer (score 0):

you need to set user_board_games in your model as sample code below

board_games model

```
class BoardGame < ApplicationRecord

  # I think you should mention user_board_games here
  has_many :user_board_games, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_board_games # you already had this line
end
```

same with user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # here is additional code
  has_many :user_board_games, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :board_games, through: :user_board_games
end
```

if you want to disconnect one user from specific board_games then you can do from UserBoardGamesController

```
class Api::UserBoardGamesController < ApplicationController

  def destroy 
    # you need two inputs here user_id and board_game_id
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    # here is why we set has_many for user_board_games above
    @user_board_game = @user.user_board_games.find(params[:board_game_id])
    @user_board_game.destroy 
  end 

end
```

**follow up question** why User and BoardGame have to mention has_many UserBoardGames, here is [rails guide reference for more detail and sample reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), basically it's to inform rails to query based from foreign key that saved in UserBoardGames,

UserBoardGames will have user_id and board_game_id fields, for example user with id 1, has 2 board games (id 2 and 3), UserBoardGames will save 2 records as follow

```
| user_id | board_game_id |
|---------|---------------|
| 1       | 2             |
| 1       | 3             |
```

when you give command @user.board_games it will query 2 records above first in UserBoardGame, and then continue by finding BoardGame records with id 2 and 3, **the key here** the connection between User and BoardGame is UserBoardGame Record

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll give that a try. I'm curious though why BoardGame and User has_many :user_board_games?

Comment: I explained above since it little bit long explanation (see my section follow up question)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on that question! So I went in and made those changes, but I happened to have a binding.pry in my destroy function in my board_games_controller and noticed that I hit it when I clicked on "remove game" in my user's library. That should have triggered the axios.delete routed to the user's board games, but instead it's deleting the games from the main db. Any thoughts?

Comment: this probably must go to user_board_games instead board games here is the sample axios.delete(`/api/users/${userId}/user_board_games/${id}`)